# Problem with Python

Tags: python, numpy

i was trying to fix my GPU to use with Theano, i had a problem with the liblas.so but python worked good, but when i did

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

(i got this from internet, bad idea, i know) now i have problems with Python:

```
python cifar10.py 
    /home/franco/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/utils.py:254: FutureWarning: Numpy has detected that you (may be) writing to an array returned
    by numpy.diagonal or by selecting multiple fields in a record
    array. This code will likely break in the next numpy release --
    see numpy.diagonal or arrays.indexing reference docs for details.
    The quick fix is to make an explicit copy (e.g., do
    arr.diagonal().copy() or arr[['f0','f1']].copy()).
      ai = a.__array_interface__
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "cifar10.py", line 46, in <module>
        import theano
      File "/home/franco/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/__init__.py", line 103, in <module>
        import theano.sandbox.cuda
      File "/home/franco/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda/__init__.py", line 448, in <module>
        from . import opt, dnn
      File "/home/franco/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda/opt.py", line 40, in <module>
        from theano.sandbox.cuda.cula import gpu_solve
      File "/home/franco/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda/cula.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pkg_resources
    ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

Now i cant use Python. How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

> **July 2018 Update**
>
> Most people should now use `pip install setuptools` (possibly with
>   `sudo`).
>
> Some may need to (re)install the `python-setuptools` package via their
>   package manager (`apt-get install`, `yum install`, etc.).
>
> This issue can be highly dependent on your OS and dev environment. See
>   the legacy/other answers below if the above isn't working for you.
>
> **Explanation**
>
> This error message is caused by a missing/broken Python `setuptools`
>   package. Per Matt M.'s comment and [setuptools issue#581](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/581),
>   the bootstrap script referred to below is no longer the recommended installation
>   method.
>
> The bootstrap script instructions will remain below, in case it's
>   still helpful to anyone.
>
> **Legacy Answer**
>
> I encountered the same `ImportError` today while trying to use pip.
>   Somehow the `setuptools` package had been deleted in my Python
>   environment.
>
> To fix the issue, run the setup script for `setuptools`:
>
> ```
> wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python
> ```
>
> (or if you don't have `wget` installed (e.g. OS X), try
>
> ```
> curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py | python
> ```
>
> possibly with `sudo` prepended.)
>
> If you have any version of
>   [`distribute`](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/merge-faq.html), or
>   any `setuptools` below 0.6, you will have to uninstall it first.*
>
> See [Installation
>   Instructions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.9.8#installation-instructions)
>   for further details.
>
> ---
>
> * If you already have a working `distribute`, upgrading it to the
>   "compatibility wrapper" that switches you over to `setuptools` is
>   easier. But if things are already broken, don't try that.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446187/no-module-named-pkg-resources